# Azure Data Factory "flatten hierarchy"

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I was hoping someone went through the same process and can help me see if the following scenario is possible.

I currently build out a pipeline that copies from an S3 bucket. That bucket contains a large number of folders. Does Azure Data factory have a way, when copying data from the S3 bucket, to them disregard the folders and just copy the files themselves? I have read that the COPY activity has "flatten hierarchy", but the big limitation that I see is that all the files are renamed and I am never sure if those are all of the files that are contained in those folders since it mentions that it only does it "in the first level of target folder".

The other problem is that the S3 bucket has nested folders (ex: "domain/yyyy/mm/dd/file") and some folders contain data and some do not. The only advantage is that all of those files contain the same schema.

The end result of this pipeline would be the following:

1) COPY files from S3 bucket without copying the folder structure
2) Load the files into an Azure Database

If anyone has done something similar with Azure Data Factory or with another tool I would greatly appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vlado101,firstly,i have to say that the `"flatten hierarchy"` which you mentioned in your question is for [sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#blob-storage-as-a-sink-type),not source:

[image]

Since your destination is SQL DB, i think this copy behavior is not related to your requirements. Based on my test(blob storage,not aws s3,sorry for that because i don't have asw services):

2 json files resident in the subfolder:

[image]

[image]

I configured source dataset:

[image]

Please make sure the [recursive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#legacy-source-model) is selected as true(Indicates whether the data is read recursively from the subfolders or only from the specified folder. Note that when recursive is set to true and the sink is a file-based store, an empty folder or subfolder isn't copied or created at the sink) and preview source data as below

[image]

Execute copy activity, all my data in the subfolder files will be transferred into destination sql db table:

[image]

Surely,this test is based on blob storage,not s3 bucket. I believe they are similar,you could test it.Any concern,please let me know.

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you, this works for me. The S3 and Azure blob storage follow the same logic so I was able to get the list of files. The only outstanding problem now is that in S3 the nested folder structure has dummy files which were needed to create those folders. So now I have about 3/4 of them as empty files so I am not sure how they would be affected by being copied into an Azure SQL DB.

The other thing that is kinda annoying is that Flatten Hierarchy also renames the files, which I am not sure why they would do that. If you have any insights they will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to use dynamic content to keep the filenames during a binary copy?  Just to know whether I should spend time figuring out whether it is possible